# How to efficiently implement constantly updating topics for a kafka consumer group

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, alert, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create an "alerting" application that has to process information from multiple kafka topics.  There exist thousands of topics, but realistically  only a few hundred need to be processed at any given time based on the alerting configuration.  If I continuously update my topics list with "subscribe" then the latency of rebalancing may delay my alerts.

**How can I efficiently implement a consumer group that subscribes to a set of constantly changing topics?**

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the answer to this today is to use assign() instead of subscribe and manually add in the new topic partitions removing any unused ones as you need to. Though it might be helpful for you to take a step back and ask if it makes more sense for the number of topics to be static and identify things to monitor by keys. That might make your life easier.